# Pass in array of objects to Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

I am new to Helm and see Helm chart values.yml with entries like:

```
extraEmptyDirMounts: []
  # - name: provisioning-notifiers
  #   mountPath: /etc/grafana/provisioning/notifiers
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to pass that in through the Helm overrides in the format of:

```
spec:
  source:
    helm:
      parameters:
      - name: extraEmptyDirMounts
        value: ???
```

I've Googled around and am yet to find a clear example of this since it seems pretty common.

Somehow, this array of objects is supposed to be encoded in the single value parameter.

Comment: That `spec: { source: { helm: } }` syntax isn't familiar to me; what tool does it go with?

Comment: @DavidMaze its a patch file yaml, but the CICD tool I'm using is ArgoCD. I think its basically the same format as the SET syntax where you can set Key/Value pairs. I did get it work with [] syntax, but that seems overly verbose.

- name: volumes[0].hostPath.path
   value: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/users/xxx/.localstack/scripts
- name: volumes[0].name
   value: localstack-scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Argo CD supports [passing in structured Helm values](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/helm/#values), either as a YAML object or as an encoded string.  I'd use `valuesObject:` over `parameters:` here.

```yaml
spec:
  source:
    helm:
      valuesObject:
        extraEmptyDirMounts:
          - name: provisioning-notifiers
            mountPath: /etc/grafana/provisioning/notifiers
```

[`parameters:`](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/helm/#helm-parameters) replicates the [`helm install --set`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set) syntax.  This is a little bit unusual format, and you can't effectively use it to provide an array of nested objects (it's possible but rather unpleasant).

Comment: Interesting! If this works, it'll definitely be cleaner then the parameters syntax!

Comment: It worked. Much cleaner then the parameters syntax. Thanks! It does "break" the UI though :), by not showing the overrides, but...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, do you want to add multiple items to `extraEmptyDirMounts`? If yes then you can repeat commented out part with different values.

For example

```
extraEmptyDirMounts:
  - name: provisioning-notifiers
    mountPath: /etc/grafana/provisioning/notifiers
  - name: another-entry
    mountPath: /etc/another/path/value
```

Comment: No, its for Helm parameter overrides.  I've updated the question.